# mysql_insert_id() in php , not return last insert id?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Mysql Query. In my table Id is **Auto-Increment** type.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO product_detail (master_detail_id,Product_code,Product_label) 
values
('8330','TOTAL','products'),('8330','010290','demo'),('8330','010639','Live demo'),
('8330','020900','demo fat'),('8330','030344','demos')";

 $insertDetails = mysql_query( $sql);
echo "last insert id-->".mysql_insert_id();
```

I am getting **last insert id--->1** but I should get it **5**. I don't know why it is happening?

*table structure*

```
     id            bigint(250)  No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
Product_code       varchar(20)  latin1_swedish_ci       No  
Product_label      varchar(500) latin1_swedish_ci       No  
master_detail_id   bigint(250)          No  None
```

Comment: have you tried without using function?

Comment: I do not see auto_increment column by that query. Could you please supply a table structure?

Comment: Are you truncating the table somewhere before the script?

Comment: @Coder you can check it .I updated my question.

Comment: i mean first try to get last id manually using "max(id) order by col" query... and check what result your getting?

Comment: @Starx Yes, I am  truncating  table.

Comment: @oecprashant, Thats the problem see my answer now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18849069/295264

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a multiple-row INSERT statement, mysql_insert_id() returns the first automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value; if no such value is generated, it returns the last explicit value inserted into the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_insert_id() will return id if you specified id column as AUTO_INCREMENT. 
You should be aware that if your id column is BIGINT type result which function returns might be wrong (this is also specified in php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 1):

For multi inserts mysql_insert_id() returns the first one, you would either need to do 5 seperate queries, running mysql_insert_id() at the end, or do 1 additional query of

```
SELECT MAX(master_detail_id) FROM product_detail or 
SELECT master_detail_id FROM product_detail 
ORDER BY master_detail_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it will only return the ID of the first item inserted, also mysql_insert_id() is deprecated as of 5.5.0 as per [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

consider using [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) instead

To workaround this behaviour you can try using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` Mysql Function

Quoting the Doc:

`Performing an INSERT or UPDATE statement using the LAST_INSERT_ID() function will also modify the value returned by the mysqli_insert_id() function.`

A Simple way to use that would be to select the last id after inserting your data
**probably this is wrong, if someone can point out the correct way?**

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO product_detail (master_detail_id,Product_code,Product_label) 
values
('8330','TOTAL','products'),('8330','010290','demo'),('8330','010639','Live demo'),
('8330','020900','demo fat'),('8330','030344','demos') select LAST_INSERT_ID() from `product_detail`";
```

**Important**

Note that if last insert fails, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will be undefined, so you'll need to add a check !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are TRUNCATING your table, the auto-increment value is reset to `1`. So whenever you run the query and ask for the last inserted id it will return `1`.

Comment: That's not the problem,

If he truncates before script, then it will always show the first item inserted which will always be 1

If he truncates after the script, it will always show 1, as after each  time he runs the query, the auto_increment from last time will already be reset

Comment: @Starx I am truncating table before the script,I do it manually.

Comment: @Starx sorry, it's hard to explain in the comments, but imagine this, the current auto_increment is 100, he truncates then runs script, the output will be 1, because he uses multi insert so it'll return the ID of the first item, not the last one.

Now let's imagine he truncates AFTER running the script, this will depend on the current value of auto_increment, but since he already truncated form the last run, then auto_increment will also be 0, which will give us the same result, 1.